# Rendering a view blocks the event loop when using Angular Material

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

We're using Angular together with Angular-material design. We noticed that during rendering some more complicated views, the scripting and rendering blocks the event loop thus it makes the whole page unresponsive for a few seconds. I created a simple page that demonstrates this problem: https://quirky-hugle-91193d.netlify.com (source code: https://github.com/lukashavrlant/angular-lag-test) If you click on the button, it will generate 200 rows with a single mat-checkbox component. There is also a counter that is refreshed every 10 ms if everything is fine. You can clearly see that the counter stops during the rendering because the event loop is blocked by the *ngFor rendering the rows. I tried to measure the length of the block, it blocks it for 400 ms on my machine.

My question is: is it completely "normal" behavior? Can it be avoided? Is it really so much data that it has to block event loop for that long? Because the delay is easily noticeable by user.

The only solution we found was to render it incrementally. I. e. render one row, wait 1 ms, render the next row, wait 1 ms etc. Isn't there a better solution?

EDIT 1: I tried also the Chrome's Performance tool. It says it spent most of the time in "scripting" phase. I tried to look at the stack traces there but wasn't able to identify the problem.

[image]

Comment: Event loop will pull data from a event queue and put in the stack so when yo say execute this code at every 10ms that's the minimum time maybe call stack is busy computing something try debugging it probably your createNewStuff function is occupying the stack for those many ms

Comment: The function `createNewStuff` creates an array of length 200. This takes less than 1 ms. The rest of it takes rendering the template by Angular or browser.

Answer (score 0):

Adding element to the DOM has a cost that you won't be able to reduce ever.

However if you look at the performance tab of the devtools while you are adding the elements you will notice a few things.

Right now it looks like you are build in dev mode, not prod. A prod build should be significantly faster.

Secondly, while there's an associated cost to adding elements in the DOM, there's also a much higher cost to instantiating those elements. Especially when it comes to Angular Material elements. They are really pretty and well made, but they are also on the heavy side when it comes to both code and html nodes. If you have to including lots of checkboxes at once, using regular html elements with a bit of css to make them look similar instead of an actual angular element might be they way to go.

In my case the actual operation of inserting everything in the DOM is ~90ms, out of the whole 350ms including the click event triggering the creation of all the elements in the ngFor loop.

The last part is further supported by the cost of elements **after** adding them, that you can also easily notice when looking at the performances. This is exacerbated by the dev mode once again, but it's present nonetheless.

So I would recommand trying it out in a more optimized build mode, and if it's still not enough maybe swap the Material component for a basic checkbox with css (maybe even a bit of svg).

Comment: Hi, thank you! Yeah, I forgot to enable production mode in this example, my fault. I enabled it. It did help, but only a little I would say. So you are basically saying that there is no other way than using simpler components or rendering less components at once...?

Comment: Pretty much, creating components has a cost, the more complex the component the higher the cost. Material checkboxes have to create the element, set attributes, create the Ripple component inside of it, set Ripple attributes, add a focus monitor on the checkbox, create event emitters and subscribe to them, etc... If you compare that to a vanilla checkbox with a touch of CSS, and while each step is fast in itself, it takes a LOT more time and resources.